# Capture logs - telnet access

Tags: python-3.x

Currently I have telnet connection using python script for capture logs from remote server, but I'am losing some information, my code is the follow:

```
def conexion(host,port):
    tn = telnetlib.Telnet(host)
    print(tn.read_until(b"> ").decode('ascii'))
    tn.write(port.encode('ascii') + b'\r\n')

    while True:
        name = 'file' + time.strftime("%y%m%d")+time.strftime("%H%M")+'.txt'
        file = open(name,'w')
        file.write(tn.read_until(b"hola",20).decode('ascii'))
        file.close()

    tn.close()
```

This generate several files, for example:
first file have logs between 1430 - 1479
second file have logs between 1585 - 1630

so I'm losing information the logs between 1479-1585, some recommendation avoid  how can i  lose logs?.